# How to properly include headers and use STL vector in c++ app?

Tags: c++, stl

I decided to try STL and use a `vector` instead of a custom made growable array class.  The problem is that I can't get anything to compile.  If I do something like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector> 

std::vector<PITEMID_CHILD> APIDL;
```

I get a bunch of messages similar to this:

> 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\cstdint(23): error C2039: 'int_least8_t': is not a member of '`global namespace''

If I change to this:

```
#include <vector> 
#include "stdafx.h"

std::vector<PITEMID_CHILD> APIDL;
```

I get this:

> 1>x:\win32testing\vectortest\vectortest.cpp(4): error C2039: 'vector': is not a member of 'std'

Inside of stdafx.h is this:

```
#pragma once

#include <windows.h>

#include "targetver.h"

// C RunTime Header Files
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <exdisp.h>
#include <shellapi.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlalloc.h>
#include <CommonControls.h>
// reference additional headers your program requires here
#include <CommCtrl.h>
```

Any idea what is going on?

Comment: What happens if you try `std::vector<int> APIDL;` and remove `#include "stdafx.h"`?

Comment: `// reference additional headers your program requires here` -- Did you follow these directions?  Admittedly, I avoid all of that precompiled header stuff due to the headaches it causes.

Comment: I got rid of the precompiled headers and put everything in the .cpp file.  That just ended up with the long line of: `1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.16.27023\include\cstdint(23): error C2039: 'int_least8_t': is not a member of '``global namespace''` items.   Now I tested with only including <vector> and it does the same, so it must be some project setting?  I tried C++ 14 and C++17 under language and still didn't work.

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. In C++ you should be including C header files by prefixing their name with a `c` and without the `.h`, such as `<cstdlib>`. `int_least8_t` should be part of the `std` namespace. If you're using precompiled headers, the line including it needs to be the first thing in the file and anything before it will be ignored.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I recommend not using `stdafx.h` and instead just deleting that file entirely. So far I've always found (precompiled) universe headers to be more trouble than they are worth.

Comment: I agree -- get rid of `stdafx.h`, turn off precompiled headers, and include the proper headers yourself.  That mess of headers `stdafx.h` is including is almost, if not just as bad as the [#include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) stuff we see here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [wikipedia documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header):

> Visual C++ will not compile anything before the `#include "stdafx.h"` in the source file, unless the compile option `/Yu'stdafx.h'` is unchecked (by default); it assumes all code in the source up to and including that line is already compiled.

The best solution is to get rid of precompiled headers.

And for your `C2039` error, it doesn't seem to be a result of line `std::vector<PITEMID_CHILD> APIDL;`. `int_least8_t` is a type defined in `cstdint` (`stdint.h`). It seems you haven't included this header file in your project.